# SQL Join question

Tags: php, sql, join

I have a table vm_category in which I fetch all rows from the category_id and caregory_name columns. I then use this in a drop-down to populate a search-filter module on the left side of the side.

Now doing so gives me a gigantic list of categories, and I'd like to narrow it down by category's sub-category. Those are organized in another table called vm_category_xref in which I have 3 columns;

- category_parent_id
- category_child_id
- category_list

What I'd like to do is specify in my query to only return the category_id and names that match a specific category_parent_id in the _xref table. Here is my current query:

```
$query = "SELECT `c`.`category_name` AS `name` , `c`.`category_id` AS `id`
          FROM `#__vm_category` AS `c` ORDER BY `c`.`category_id`;";
```

I am not familiar with JOIN enough to figure this out, but I know it should be rather simple, and any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to use backticks on everything, you know... None of these are SQL keywords (AFAIK)

Comment: i believe that NAME is a SQL Keyword...

Comment: @Leslie:  NAME is not a reserved word, at least not in MySQL.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    c.category_name AS name, 
    c.category_id AS id
FROM #__vm_category AS c 
    INNER JOIN vm_category_xref xr
    ON xr.category_child_id = c.category_id
WHERE xr.category_parent_id = 5 /* the parent_id you want to filter on */
ORDER BY c.category_id;
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need but didn't work, is it missing an AS after the JOIN vm_category_xref ?

Comment: I think the `AS` is not required in this case. Try putting back the backticks around `#__vm_category` (is that the table name, with the pound sign, or am I missing something?).

Comment: You were right in using the #__ before the table names, this also works!

Comment: Actually, I don't know what the `#__` is for. If that's not part of the table name, just remove this prefix and the backticks, and everythink will look more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.category_name as name, c.category_id as id
FROM vm_category as c
INNER JOIN vm_category_xref as x ON
    x.category_parent_id = c.category_id
ORDER BY c.category_id
```

Essentially this returns category_name and category_id only for records that have a category_id that equals a category_parent_id in _xref.

Comment: Thanks! Two things; they all have a parent id, I need to be able to manually specify one in particular.

Comment: Sorr,y second thing is; I'd like to keep the AS clauses for each field as they are used elsewhere as name and as id, how would I write that?

Comment: I have modified it for the as clauses.
The query as it stands will provide all categories whose id matches a parent_id. If you want to filter by a particular id, place something like `WHERE c.category_id = #YOUR_ID_HERE#` after the inner join clause

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.category_name AS name , c.category_id AS id
FROM vm_category c 
INNER JOIN vm_category_xref x on c.category_id = x.category_child_id
ORDER BY c.category_id
```

I may have picked the wrong fields to join on but whichever are the 2 same fields in c and x are the ones you should put in the join condition

Answer (score 0):

```
select vc.category_id, vc.category_name 
from vm_category vc, vm_category_xref vcx
where vc.category_id = vc.category_parent_id
```

Comment: Do not encourage the use of the comma separated syntax for tables references. Instead use the JOIN syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
 c.category_name AS name 
,c.category_id AS id 
FROM 
vm_category AS c 
join vm_category_xref vcx 
    on c.category_id = vcx.category_parent_id
where vcx.category_parent_id = ? 
ORDER BY c.category_id;
```

Replace `?` with the id you want to match.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to retrieve category_name and category_ID only for certain category parent IDs on the xref.

I typically use IN for situations like these.

I'm assuming that category_id in vm_category maps to category_parent_id in vm_category_xref.

So...

```
SELECT CATEGORY_NAME, CATEGORY_ID 
FROM VM_CATEGORY
WHERE CATEGORY_ID IN
(SELECT CATEGORY_PARENT_ID FROM VM_CATEGORY_XREF
WHERE CATEGORY_PARENT_ID IN ('XXX', 'YYY', 'ZZZ'))
```

XXX, YYY, ZZZ are the IDs for the categories you want.